# Get next element in 2 foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I don't know how to say it in the title, but you'll understand with an example.
I've a database, where I store data in column named `propriety` and another column `value`.  When I do my SQL request, I get this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [propriety] => propriety1
        [value] => value1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [propriety] => propriety2
        [value] => value2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [propriety] => propriety3
        [value] => value3
    )
```

I would like to display it like this one:

- Propriety : Value

But when I do my 2 foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
       echo $k . ' : ' . $v . '<br>';
   }
}
```

It returns:

- Propriety : Propriety1
- Value : Value1

etc ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two `foreach` loops to do this, it can be done with one:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
   echo $row['propriety'].' : '.$row['value'].'<br>';
}
```

Assuming you actually want the values returned by the database.

Comment: Hell yeah, Exactly what I need, didn't think about that ! Thanks you sir

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative extracting `value` and re-indexing by `propriety`:

```
foreach(array_column($array, 'value', 'propriety') as $propriety => $value) {
    echo "$propriety : $value<br>";
}
```

This assumes that each `propriety` will be unique.